# Trying to understand a method in this code

Tags: java

Now I found this code online and I found it interesting, the loop has quite a good function and it was well although for me I had issues with some parts.  understand what he is trying to do here:

```
int pos = -1;
int index = 0;
while(pos == -1 && index < network.size()){
     if(network.get(index).getName().equals(current))
          pos = index;
          index++;
     }
```

So i wondered why didnt he use this

```
int pos = -1;
int index = 0;
while(pos == -1 && index < network.size()) {
    if(network.get(index).getName().equals(current)) {
         pos = index;
    }
    index++;
    .
    .
    .
}
```

Comment: Are you *just* asking why the author didn't have braces around `pos = index;`?

Comment: Well what don't you understand about it? The braces part is just a matter of style - personally I *always* put braces around single-line loop/if statements, but that really is just a style issue. You should be a lot clearer about exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Even your comment isn't clear, and all the relevant information should be in the *question*. What *exactly* do you not understand about the `canRedeem` method? Do you not understand what it's meant to achieve, or what some portion of the code actually does?

Comment: @JonSkeet Thanks. I have seen why i was having difficulties.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You missed the indentation. What you want is exactly what he did. The only difference is that he omits the brackets.

Without brackets

```
while(pos == -1 && index < network.size()){
    if(network.get(index).getName().equals(current))
        pos = index;
    index++;
}
```

With brackets

```
while(pos == -1 && index < network.size()){
    if(network.get(index).getName().equals(current)) {
        pos = index;
    }
    index++;
}
```